# Remove files with 000 permissions in current directory

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to remove the files with begins with pattern `sed*`. Filename length should be equal to `nine` and also it should have `chmod` permissions as `000` from the current directory in Linux. But couldn't able to do it. Below are the approaches which I have tried for your reference.

**Approach-1**

```
ls sed* | find . -maxdepth 9 -type f -perm 000 -delete
```

**Approach-2**

```
ls sed* | awk '{if (length($1)==9) print $1}' | find . -perm 000 -delete
```

Comment: Umm... Why the `ls sed*`? `find` does not read its standard input.  If you only want to act on files matching `sed*`, use `-name 'sed*'` with `find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `find` only:

```
find ./* -type f -name 'sed??????' -perm 0
```

to disable the *find*'s default recursive behavior, add `-maxdepth 0` to the command:

```
find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type f -name 'sed??????' -perm 0
```

add `-delete` to the command to delete those reported files with 0 (no) permission.

Comment: Files in sub-directories also is shown in result, but i need only in current directory. Also output is coming as  ```./``` at the beginning of each file ```./sedtuiykk``` which needs to be ignored

Comment: I tried the edited command shared above. But still  ```./``` is getting appending at the beginning of each file

Comment: @user78873 what is the matter of that when you finally want do delete those files? another way would be  `find ./* -maxdepth 0 -type f -name 'sed??????' -perm 0 -printf '%f\n'` if you have GNU find.

Comment: I thought its looks from root and display the  results. So only asked it.  Anyway its working fine now. Thanks